# Multiple database or a single Database?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, security, saas

We are planning a SAAS application.

Now we are at the database point. A single relational database with all our client or a multiple database for each client?
I think a single database would be ok but taking the proper design and securtity.
What about performance?

It is a payroll SAAS so each client need to do his employee administration based on his company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if you will maintain application for every client independently. If it is "classic" SAAS application, where you will have many clients and you are not ready to change your application until most of the clients require some change, then one database is what you should do. On the other hand, if you are just hosting solution for 5 clients, and might happen that client 3 wants something different (which is very likely with payroll applications) and you want to fulfill his requirements, then go with separate databases.

Regarding performance (if you have SaaS and one database), there are many ways to do partitioning, and other performance improvement techniques (replication for example) which you can implement if you end up with performance issues...and in that case, you will have to maintain only one database.

Comment: Thank you ! very helpful, This will help me take the correct aproach (single database)

Answer (score 3):

If you use a single database, it also affects your backup and security considerations.  By putting it all into single database, then a backup/restore will affect all customers.  It will also affect your scaling decisions.  A DB per customer means that you can add new db servers and rebalance databases.  A single database means that you may need to be able to cluster in the future.

On the other hand, multiple dbs means more administration overhead, and also more work when you deliver enhancements that require schema modification.

Answer (score 1):

This is a design trade-off

Performance has nothing to do with multiple vs single database unless you plan a distributed data server model (each database on a separate server).

Keeping multiple databases add some unnecessary work for you. Let's assume at the point you don't know what is going to happen and which is the best solution (if customers need much change, do databases increase in size rapidly...) in this case I suggest starting with one database and if the business is growing up rapidly then you can separate each customers db easily.

Albert Einstein: `Everything should be made as simple as possible; But not simpler.`

Answer (score 1):

If it's Software as a Service, then you might want to consider resilience as well as simply performance.

Personally, I'd go for a single database for all clients, but replicate it across multiple servers with load balancing to ensure decent performance when they're all hitting it at the same time at the end-of-month/payday. This also gives you a failover in the event of one server crashing.

For a larger application, I might even consider one or two database servers with read/write for admin, with multiple read only database servers for reporting, again using replication. And you can take a single server down for fast, offline and consistent database backups while still retaining online access.